# How to use ajax and update img src and call php function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There is a list of checkboxes. User clicks on image of a "unchecked checkbox". Ajax sends request to php script which updates database and echo's new image source of a "checked checkbox". This works fine, and is below:

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="markBox" id="<?php echo $box->id ?>" name="markBox"><img src="<?php echo ( $box->complete == 1 ) ? "/images/checkbox-filled.png" : "/images/checkbox-empty.png" ?>" id="checkbox-<?php echo $box->id ?>" /></a>
```

markBox.js:

```
        $.ajax( {

            type: "POST",
            url: "/scripts/markBox.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,

            success: function( imageSource ) {
                image.attr( 'src', imageSource );
            }
        } );
```

markBox.php:

```
    //Return result
    if ( $box->complete == 1 )
        echo "/images/checkbox-filled.png";
    else
        echo "/images/checkbox-empty.png";

    exit;
```

The challenge is that I have php function that is called earlier, above the list of checkboxes, to display to user how boxes are checked and how many are not. I want this box to be called and refresh as the image does. How do I rerun the php function to run again once the ajax comes back?

HTML:

```
            <div class="markBox"><?php echo $results->getCountComplete() ?> Complete</div>
        <div class="markBox"><?php echo $results->getCountNotComplete() ?> Incomplete</div>
```

Comment: In your `success` callback?

Comment: You don't have to count this on server... Js can count it too...

Comment: @inf3rno The answer below is able to count in JS only, but I do need to store data to a database. What do you think?

Comment: @OneTrickPony Yes, but how do I reference the php function call and get it to run again?

Comment: In your original code with a new ajax call in the success callback...
If you want to store data in database you can do that by every php call.. Just store the data before your response...

Comment: Edited klickagent answer: http://jsfiddle.net/teeEx/2/
Somehow my modifications were not accepted, or just late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need ajax at all: (unless you don't want to store your data to a database or a file): I hope this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/teeEx/

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="check1"><span class="checked">&nbsp;</span></a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="check2"><span class="unchecked">&nbsp;</span></a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="check3"><span class="unchecked">&nbsp;</span></a>

<div id="result"></div>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
span{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
}
span.checked{
   background: green;
}
span.unchecked{
   background: black;
}
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var a_obj = $(this);
    var obj = a_obj.children('span');
    if( obj.is('.checked')){
     obj.removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');   
    } else {
     obj.removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');   
    }

    var all = a_obj.parent();
    var countChecked = all.find('span.checked').length;
    var countunChecked = all.find('span.unchecked').length;
    $('#result').html('checked '+countChecked+'; unckecked: '+countunChecked);
});
```

Comment: The example works great, but I do need to store it to a database. What do you think?

Comment: what do you need to save in your db? i assume the state of the checkbox? then simply add your ajax request inside the click handler.

Comment: @klickagent.ch I edited your code. Added the ajax call, and simplified its checking logic. Btw I don't think he really needs ajax, this issue can be solved with a simple submit button...